# Regex for numpy's 1D advanced indexing syntax - How to deal with optional trailing comma

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex to match a subset of the Python numpy advanced indexing syntax for 1D arrays.

So far I have this:

```
^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\s*\[\s*\[(\s*[-+]?\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*,\s*)*\]\s*\]$
```

This regex can match successfully the following:

```
a[[10,]]
a[[+10,-10,20,]]
a [ [ + 10 , - 10 , 20 , ] ]
a[[]]
```

However, the trailing comma in Python lists is optional and not required. Unfortunately, my regex fails to validate the following:

```
a[[10]]
a[[10,10]]
```

Please note the missing comma at the end of the inner brackets. If I add a `?` next to the `,` of my regex pattern, then the above pattern is validated. However, then the regex also validates items that are numerical expressions (e.g.,: `a[[10+10,10]]`) which is not desirable.

What I essentially want is to have a list of integer numbers, in the inner square brackets, separated by commas and allow for a trailing comma. Also, these numbers are allowed to have a `-` or `+` prefix.

Can someone provide me with a solution that validates the pattern described above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex to allow for an optional number *not followed by a comma* prior to the closing `]`:

```
^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\s*\[\s*\[(\s*[-+]?\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*,\s*)*(\s*[-+]?\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*)?\]\s*\]$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LF9SJj/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I like your solution because it is very simple and easy to understand. However, I am a bit concerned with the fact that this solution includes a repetition for the number regex (i.e., `\s*[-+]?\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*`). Is there any way to avoid this repetition but not make the regex hard to read (i.e., without strange lookaheads etc)?

Comment: @AstrOne yeah, the repetition is unfortunate but (I'm pretty sure) you have to have that group which doesn't contain a `,` to match e.g. `a[[10]]` as - as you found - making the comma optional allows the regex to match `a[[10+10]]`. I did look into use lookaheads but they don't really simplify the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick. I will accept your answer as it is the one that works and is simple at the same time. Having said that, the other two answers were also great and quite educational I have to say.

Comment: @AstrOne thanks. I almost always find I learn something from reading the other answers myself.

Answer (score 2):

Have to mix the optional with the required in a precise way.

`^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\s*\[\s*\[(?:\s*(?:[-+]\s*)?[1-9][0-9]*(?:\s*,\s*(?:[-+]\s*)?[1-9][0-9]*)*(?:\s*,)?\s*)?\]\s*\]$`

https://regex101.com/r/D3wzYb/1

Expanded

```
 ^    
 [_a-zA-Z] 
 \w* \s* \[ \s* \[ 
 (?:
      \s* 
      (?: [-+] \s* )?
      [1-9] [0-9]* 
      (?:
           \s* , \s* 
           (?: [-+] \s* )?
           [1-9] [0-9]* 
      )*
      (?: \s* , )?
      \s* 
 )?
 \] \s* \] 
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
(?i)(?!.*\d\s*[+*%-]\s*\d)^[a-z_]\w*\s*\[\s*\[(\s*[-+]?\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*,?\s*)*\]\s*\]$
```

would do then.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpNCCJ/1/)

Here, we'd fail those undesired operations using some subexpression such as,

```
(?!.*\d\s*[+*%-]\s*\d)
```

and we'd include it in the beginning of our expression, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I really appreciate it. Your solution almost solves the problem described in my question. I should have explained what is the numpy advanced indexing syntax. I will edit my question now to include an explanation. What I actually want is to have a list of integer numbers (in the inner brackets) separated by commas and allow for a -/+ prefix on those numbers. Unfortunately, your solution wrongly validates: `a[[10 10]]`. By replacing your `[+*%-]` with `[ +*%-]` the problem is fixed. Also, are the `*` and `%` required?